# Изображения "утекают" в конец документа

Tags: latex

Готовлю документ *\documentclass[12pt]{article}*. По сути - фотоальбом самый простой. Несколько *figure* разделённых небольшими кусами текста. Типичный кусок документа:

```
\section{Название секции}

Предваряющий текст.

\begin{figure}{H}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../../../Album/1950/1950_001}
    \caption[Подпись к рисунку]{Подпись к рисунку}
    \label{fig:1950_001}
\end{figure}

Дополняющий текст
```

Проблема в том, что начиная с некоторой позиции в документе, картинки начали уплывать в конец документа, а текст идёт подряд без картинок.

Я пробовал фиксировать с помощью [h], [h!] и [H] - никакого эффекта. про

```
\usepackage{float}
```

я знаю. Самое непонятное в том, что до какого-то момента, фотографии и текст идут правильно - вместе. А потом вдруг начинают разъезжаться...

Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

У теха есть несколько (порядка десятка, но это не точно) параметров, которыми он руководствуется при размещении плавающих объектов. Например, есть просто счетчик, задающий число флоатов на странице `totalnumber`, по умолчанию равный 3 (если Львовский нас не обманывает). На самом деле он не один, с ним работают похожие счетчики для верха и низа страницы. А еще есть параметры, регулирующие не количество, а площадь, занимаемую плавающими объектами на странице. В общем, это все жутко сложно и есть подозрение, что даже параметр `H` с этими механизмами не всегда справляется.

Так собственно вопрос же в том, как разместить, а не почему оно себя так ведет? Для фотоальбома я не вижу смысла использовать плавающие объекты как сущность. Если от плавающих объектов нужны только подписи, то можно воспользоваться командой `\captionof{счётчик флоата}{сама подпись}`, которая создает стандартную подпись вне плавающего объекта (естественно, с ней можно использовать и `\label{}`). Например для рисунков это будет выглядеть как-то так `\captionof{figure}{Подпись к рисунку}\label{fig:fig-1}`. Команда живет в пакете `caption`.

С приложенным примером в итоге должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
\section{Название секции}

Предваряющий текст.

{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../../../Album/1950/1950_001}
    \captionof{figure}[Подпись к рисунку]{Подпись к рисунку}
    \label{fig:1950_001}

}

Дополняющий текст
```

Comment: Исправил в одном месте - всё прекрасно отработало. Хотел уже поставить жирную галку, но (паранойя программиста) решил точно так же исправить пятью строками ниже. И увы - не получилось. Ругается на *captionof*, говорит, что **вне объекта float**. Если закомментировать этот оператор, то документ создаётся и картинка встаёт на нужное место. Но без подписи...

Comment: Виноват! Очепятка вышла :-( Всё работает!